# can't connect date_select to the target stimulusjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I am trying to connect my form.date_select to my stimulusjs controller but I can't do it.
I have the following code

```
        = f.date_select :date_of_birth, :order => [:day, :month, :year], selected: Date.today, prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, start_year: Date.current.year, end_year:Date.current.year - 100, data: {signupform_target: 'dateOfBirth', action: 'signupform#isValidDob' }
```

I am trying to connect this to dateOfBirth target. my controller:

```
export default class extends Controller {
static targets = ['firstName', 'firstNameInput', 'lastName', 'lastNameInput', 'email', 'emailInput',
                'password', 'passwordInput', 'dateOfBirth', 'dateOfBirthInput', 'button', 'warning']

isValidDob() {
console.log(this.dateOfBirthTarget);
}
```

This is the error I get.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z7Jz.png

This is my form

```
  = form_for(@user, url: settings_public_path(locale: I18n.locale, id: @user),
              data: { controller: "generalsettings" }) do |f|
    .field.pb-4
      = f.label t('sign_in.your_email')
      = f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control field-text-input settings-input', disabled: 'disabled'
      %div{style: 'font-size: .9rem !important;'}
        =t('settings.cant_change_email')
    .names-flex.pb-4
      .name-div.first-name
        = f.label t('sign_up.fname')
        = f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control field-text-input settings-input', disabled: @user.provider.present?, data: { generalsettings_target: 'firstName', action: 'generalsettings#isValidCombination'}
      .name-div.last-name
        = f.label t('sign_up.lname')
        = f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control field-text-input settings-input', disabled: @user.provider.present?, data: { generalsettings_target: 'lastName', action: 'generalsettings#isValidCombination'}
    .field.pb-4
      = f.label t('sign_up.dob')
      .dob-picker
        = f.date_select :date_of_birth, :order => [:day, :month, :year], prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, start_year: Date.current.year, end_year:Date.current.year - 100, disabled: @user.provider.present?, data: { generalsettings_target: 'dateOfBirth', action: 'generalsettings#isValidCombination'}
    = f.submit t('settings.save'), class: 'sign-button save_button', data: { generalsettings_target: 'button'}
```

Comment: If it is like with values, your target should be on the same element as your `data-controller` not your `data-action` (this is just a guess though)

Comment: Can you show us your HTML so we can see how and where the controller is defined?

Comment: As far as I can see your controller is called generalsettings and in your error is signupform. Basically the error says that you are missing target element for the singupform controller.

Comment: @DenisOmerovic changed "signup" to "generalsettings" and I still have the same error, but for generalsettings controller

Comment: I think it's because date_select is actually 3 <select></select> in html.

Comment: https://imgur.com/k8X5PKz

Comment: solved this. the solution is here
https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/stimulusjs-connect-target-for-date-select/4514/5